# Doxygen: Images not shown in the chm file generated

Tags: doxygen

I have copied folder names reports with html files and images which are necessary to the HTML output folder of the doxygen. In one of the pages I am trying to provide a link to the external HTML document(within reports directory).In the chm file the HTML document is opening but the images are not displayed.When I open the index.html file in the html output directory and try to open the link the images are shown properly.